# osx mariaDB how to set max_allowed_packet

Tags: mysql, mariadb, max-allowed-packet

I am trying to set 'max_allowed_packet' in 'my.cnf' which on my iMac is located in:

```
    /usr/local/etc/
```

I've tried:

```
    SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;
```

I've also tried adding a section:

```
    [mysqld]
    SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;
```

But neither have worked such that the setting is carried forward for reboots.  If I open a terminal and enter:

```
    SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;
```

Directly into the terminal it works find, but isn't kept on reboot, how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution works when editing `my.cnf`, No need for `SET GLOBAL` prefix:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=500M
```